# Flutter - Bloc only emits state when the state is not extending Equatable

Tags: flutter, events, stream, state, bloc

I recently started using bloc and im stuck here.

I have a state:

```
class BasketState extends Equatable{
  final Map<Item, int> itemsOrdered;

  BasketState(this.itemsOrdered);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [itemsOrdered]
}
```

And the following bloc:

```
class BasketBloc extends Bloc<BasketEvent, BasketState> {
  Map<Item, int> _itemsOrdered = {};
  BasketBloc() : super(BasketState({}));

  @override
  Stream<BasketState> mapEventToState(BasketEvent event) async* {
    if (event is BasketAdd) {
      _itemsOrdered.putIfAbsent(event.item, () => event.amount);
    } else if (event is BasketRemove) {
      _itemsOrdered.remove(event.item);
    }
    yield BasketState(_itemsOrdered);
  }
}
```

Only the first time I send the BasketAdd event the bloc emits the state, then if I send the BasketAdd event again, the bloc emits nothing.

The only thing that worked is to remove the Equatable from the state, and I dont know why.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equatable is using that get props function to do the comparison.

Change

```
  @override
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
```

to

```
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [itemsOrdered];
```

and try again

EDIT: The answer is in the comments now but another possible problem is mutability. In this case, rather than yielding itemsOrdered we should yield a new Map each time.

```
  yield BasketState(new Map<Item, int>.from(itemsOrdered));
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to put that while writing the question. In my real app is correct, now I edited the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, after that I'm speculating.  A quick, dirty workaround is to yield a "loading" state (call it whatever, BasketLoading) then yield BasketState again.  I suspect what's happening is it's comparing two mutable objects (map) that it thinks is immutable.  Rather than yield BasketState(_itemsOrdered) I wonder if yield BasketState(new Map<Item, int>.from(_itemsOrdered)) would work.

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating)

> **Equatable** properties should always be copied rather than modified. If
> an **Equatable** class contains a **List** or **Map** as properties, be sure to
> use **List.from** or **Map.from** respectively to ensure that equality is
> evaluated based on the values of the properties rather than the
> reference.

```
yield BasketState(Map<Item, int>.from(itemsOrdered));
```